# php mysql connection timeour error

Tags: php, mysql

I am using php 4 and mysql4. In application I need to generate report by using around 6 to 8 tables. But when I tried to generate, it takes more than 20 mins and shows connection timeout and nothing is generated.. How can I increase the connection time and I need to know whether this error comes from PHP or MYSQL..?

Comment: post some code where you generate the tables so we can analyze.

Answer (score 1):

```
//your mysterious loop {
  echo 'i\'m here';
  flush();
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php